# Use data gleaned from a file with PHP in a JavaScript alert

Tags: javascript, php, html, file

I am making a website whose main feature is a list of files in each directory, which can be downloaded. I also have an /assets directory, in which the directory tree is copied, but with the necessary images/scripts for each page, and also .csv files for comments, and an information file for each file, which I would like to display in a JavaScript alert when the user clicks a button.

I dynamically list all files in each directory with PHP, along with file size and some other information. I have managed to get a button for each file, which alerts 'No info' if the information file doesn't exist. However, if the file does exist, I get one of two JavaScript errors, either `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal` or `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`.

My source code for the buttons with the errors ends up being split over two lines after the final quote mark in the alert, so I used the PHP `trim()` function to remove any `\n`s or `\r`s left in the file, but it did nothing.

As for the second error, I tried using PHP's `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars` to remove any quote marks in the file (because this error must have something to do with that) but again, this did nothing.

My code for listing the files is this:

```
foreach(glob('*') as $filename){
    if ($filename[strlen($filename) - 1] != '~'){
        $info = '';
        $file_type = filetype($filename);
        $infoPath = __DIR__ . '/files' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . $filename . '.txt';
        if (file_exists($infoPath)){
            $handle = fopen($infoPath, 'r');
            $info = fread($handle, filesize($infoPath));
            fclose($handle);
        }
        if ($info == ''){
            $info = 'No info :(';
        }
        if ($file_type == 'dir'){
            echo "<tr><td><img src=\"/assets/images/$file_type.png\" alt=\"$file_type\" width=\"16px\" height=\"16px\" /><a href=\"$filename\">$filename</a></td><td>-</td><td>" . date ("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($filename)) . "</td><td><button onclick=\"alert('" . trim(htmlentities(htmlspecialcharacters($info))) . "')\">Info</button></td></tr>";
        }
        else{   
            echo "<tr><td><img src=\"/assets/images/$file_type.png\" alt=\"$file_type\" width=\"16px\" height=\"16px\" /><a href=\"$filename\">$filename</a></td><td>".filesize($filename)."</td><td>" . date ("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($filename)) . "</td><td><button onclick=\"alert('" . trim(htmlentities(htmlspecialcharacters($info))) . "')\">Info</button></td></tr>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

So, first of all, how do I terminate the string literal, and secondly, what do I do about the supposed argument list?

I have a feeling I may have to use AJAX, but I would have thought that I could just echo a string into the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several errors in your echo. The escapes and concatenations are not good.

- You should use `'` to better visibility of the escaped codes.
- Some php codes are not concatenate correctly.
- The CSS codes (width and heigth) must be in a `style` attribute.

Example :

```
echo '<tr><td><img src="/assets/images/'.$file_type.png.'" alt="'.$file_type.'" style="width:16px; height:16px;" /><a href="'.$filename.'">'.$filename.'</a></td><td>-</td><td>'.date("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($filename)).'</td><td><button onclick="alert(\"'.trim(htmlentities(htmlspecialcharacters($info))).'\")">Info</button></td></tr>';
```

Actually, I think you don't need to use Ajax because your code does not need to be called on specific event but one time on page load (correct me if I'm wrong).

So, just correct your `echo` and it should be fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping to tidy my code up, but unfortunately it hasn't fixed my problems. I think it might be more to do with the format of data from the file. Thanks anyway though, my code looks a lot neater :)

Comment: You're welcome. Is the `alert` onclick event works ? Or has the returned error changed ?

Comment: For some reason, my browser wasn't actually registering the new code, but I've restarted my computer, and those errors have gone, now it just says `SyntaxError: Illegal character`, for every button that I click. I'm trying  to fix it now.

Comment: It turns out your code had a slight mistake in it, I think, because the `\"` in the `alert` made my browser think it was the end of the attribute, and I had two attributes right next to each other. I changed it slightly, and got it to work for all info files except the one with the quotes in it, for which I get the `Unterminated string literal` error. I think I have to convert them to entities, but `htmlentities()` doesn't seem to work. I'm working on it.

Comment: `htmlentities()` seems to be converting other characters, such as the &, to entities, but not the apostrophes in the info file.

Comment: Have you tried to convert the output in JSON ? `echo json_encode('<your html code>');`

Comment: It turns out I was being silly and not using `htmlentities()` correctly - I forgot to use the ENT_QUOTES flag. Thanks a lot for your time and help anyway, the tidying up of the code really helped!

Comment: I'm glad you solve this and happy if I helped you. Please, post your solution in a new answer just in case somebody else looking for it. ; ) Good luck.